# Exception: Invalid method Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login::__

Tags: magento2, php

I keep getting this error:

> Invalid method Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login::__

method:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Google\Client $socialConnectGoogleClient,
        \Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Facebook\Client $socialConnectFacebookClient,
        \Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Twitter\Client $socialConnectTwitterClient,
        \Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Pixelpin\Client $socialConnectPixelpinClient,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->socialConnectGoogleClient = $socialConnectGoogleClient;
        $this->socialConnectFacebookClient = $socialConnectFacebookClient;
        $this->socialConnectTwitterClient = $socialConnectTwitterClient;
        $this->socialConnectPixelpinClient = $socialConnectPixelpinClient;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }
```

I also put my module on github if you want to dig a bit further: https://github.com/CallumBrankin/Magento2-Inchoo-Social-Plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace in all the project the occurences of `$this->__(....)` with `__('...')`.
So remove `$this` from the translation function.

Comment: so in [login.phtml](https://github.com/CallumBrankin/Magento2-Inchoo-Social-Plugin/blob/master/app/code/Inchoo/SocialConnect/view/frontend/templates/inchoo/socialconnect/login.phtml) do i need to change every single "$this->_(....)" to " _('...')"?

Comment: i've changed all the "$this->_(....)" to " _('...')" in login.phtml and now it works